# How to configure WinMerge to treat lines as single differences?

Tags: winmerge

I'm using WinMerge and fighting with it's desire to treat groups of line differences as a single difference block. For my needs this behavior makes it difficult to merge, I want to go one line at a time. I've read the  help and searched the web, but can't figure out how to control this option.

Is this not configurable? No way to work with differences one line at a time?

Comment: Did you try: WinMerge, Edit, Options: Compare General and then enable (check) Match similar lines ?

Comment: @John - thank you, that worked, though I don't understand why; seems like it would do the opposite, like clearing that check box would yield the behavior I want. Either way, it works and I appreciate your time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach (you say worked) is within the Compare Options.

Open WinMerge, Edit, Options: Compare General and then enable (check) Match similar lines.

This appears to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a line-oriented compare product, then WinMerge is not
your right tool.

The most you can do is reduce the size of the groups to the minimum.

This is done in menu
*Edit > Options... > Compare (General)*.
Choose for "Diff algorithm" the value of "minimal", defined
in the Help as:

> minimal: Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.

The comparison will be slower with this option, but the groups may be
smaller.